# jQuery - Event binding on dynamically created elements from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, click

I would like to bind an onClick event handler to each anchor within an iFrame. Consider the iframe as a IM/chat client and hence the anchor links are not present at iframe load time. I have no control over the iFrame source and hence anchors cannot have any attributes set.

*Appreciate this topic has been discussed several times, but I cannot find an example with an iFrame, and have had no success after a good deal of reading.*

I understand I should be using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Heres what I have:

HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://...." scrolling="no" id="chatFrame"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
// wait for frame to load
$('#chatFrame').on('load', function(){

    $('#chatFrame').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefaults(e);
        alert("link clicked!" );
    });
});
```

I get no errors, but the alert is not fired on click and the link takes me to a new window (as expected default behavior).

Can anyone advise on how to bind to these iFrame anchors?

Comment: Note typo in `e.preventDefaults` ... remove last `s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to get inside the iframe using [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). An iframe has it's own window so the elements in that window are not accessible doing things like `$('iframe a')`

Try

```
$('#chatFrame').on('load', function(){
    $(this).contents().find('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        alert("link clicked!" );
    });
});
```

This also assumes that the iframe is on same domain as the page or you won't be able to access it

Comment: Wonderful, thank you - been hung up on that for some time. Good point on the cross-origin, i'll add a server side proxy to cope with that.

Comment: good luck with the proxy...that can be a major challenge all it's own depending on what resources need to be proxied